# django + apache: logging common output

Tags: python, django, apache, logging

I am trying to find out how to log the common output (not only the errors) for my Django WSGI application that I am running with Apache. Currently, Apache logs errors correctly, but not the common console output. Apache has the following logging configuration for this app:

```
CustomLog /home/rtubiopa/server_master/logs/access.log combined
CustomLog /home/rtubiopa/server_master/logs/ssl_request.log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}s %{SSL_CIPHER}s \"%r\" %b"
ErrorLog /home/rtubiopa/server_master/logs/error.log
```

My Django application logging configuration is the following:

```
    'periodically': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'rpc4django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'accounts': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
```

I have been reading through the Apache documentation for logging but I could not find any references to how to send the common output to an specific logging file. I know that I can do this directly through the Django loggers (that I have just configured to send everything out to the console), but I would like to keep it this way, so that whoever handles my Django app (Apache in this case), handles the output as well.

Any ideas about what can I be doing wrong?